# Are units like Pikyuon ever useful?

Tags: grand-summoners

I have quite a few of these Spirit-type units cluttering up my inventory and was wondering if I should just sell them or use them in some other way.  Specifically it's the different elemental versions of the little alligator-looking thing:

- Pikyuon: Light
- Mikyuon: Water
- Mokyuon: Earth
- Rekyuon: Fire
- Dakyuon: Dark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like they are used after limit breaks.

> [It’s used to boost your units stats after limit breaking them](https://www.facebook.com/GrandSummonersGlobal/posts/what-am-i-supposed-to-do-with-these-mikyuon-things-just-sell-or-use-for-leveling/645541055881446/)